# Was tust du da mit dem Hammer vs was machst du da mit dem Hammer

Tags: meaning

I have read up a bit on the difference between machen and tun, but I would just like some opinions on the difference between these two specific sentences, whether there is any difference in meaning/implication please

> Was machst du da mit dem Hammer?

> Was tust du da mit dem Hammer?

My assumption is that both make sense, but with machen you are more asking what specific task they are carrying out with the hammer, whereas with tun you are asking more generally why they have a hammer.

Is there any truth in my theory?

Answer (score 5):

Without any context, there is no difference. "Tun" (*to do*) is a more general word, "machen" (*to do* too, but also *to make*) is a wee bit more specific. "Tun [mit]" is more like *operate sth.*, whereas "machen [mit]" is either the same or - depending on context - can lean towards *to create [using sth.]*.

Answer (score 4):

There's no real difference in meaning between the two sentences, but they belong to different [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)).

> Was machst du da mit dem Hammer?

is a bit more casual than

> Was tust du da mit dem Hammer?

Comment: Da "casual" lt. Deinem Link kein Extrem bezeichnet ist unklar, welchem Register denn nun "tun" angehört. M.E. sind beides gleichwertige Hilfsverben. Wenn man nicht recht weiß, was der andere denn mit dem Hammer macht oder tut ist es auch schwierig, etwas anderes als ein Hilfsverb zu verwenden - wobei natürlich sein kann, dass man grob sieht, es wird was gedengelt oder es wird zerschmettert, aber man möchte es genauer wissen.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a slight difference in meaning. I am not sure though, whether other speakers of German would agree. It might be a matter of subjective opinion:

Both sentences can be used when referring to a strange way of working with the hammer. But in situations where the hammer is not used for its intended purpose, *Was machst du da mit dem Hammer* would be the only option. The latter could also refer to a person who is just carrying a hammer, but not working with it at all, for instance in the meaning: "What are you up to with that hammer?". Again, *Was tust du da mit dem Hammer* would not fit in such a situation, imho.

Comment: Klingt, als wolltest Du sagen, dass man beides nicht verwendet, wenn jmd. sachgemäß mit dem Hammer hantiert. Das kann ich sowenig nachvollziehen wie die Tendenz, da eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung herauszuhören bzw. zu lesen.

Comment: @userunknown Das ist nicht impliziert. Ich habe mich nur auf den Teil der Bedeutung bezogen, an dem sich die beiden Sätze m. M. n. unterscheiden.